# Как перехватить долгое нажатие на пункт меню

Tags: android, kotlin, menu

Я осваиваю kotlin и андроид разработку. Хочу, чтобы при коротком нажатии на пункт меню совершалось одно действие, а при долгом - другое.

Вот так у меня создается меню

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu)
    return true
}
```

а вот перехватчик нажатия

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    return when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.settings -> {
            val intent = Intent(this, SettingsActivity ::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            true
        }
        else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

Comment: попробуйте setOnLongClickListener()

Comment: @Эникейщик, можно подробнее? Я совсем новичок и не знаю, куда нужно "пробовать"

Comment: Так делать очень нежелательно. Если вам нужны другие действия просто добавьте новые пункты меню.

Comment: поддержу @Style-7. меню тулбара предназначено для обычных кликов. мы можете сделать свою разметку и "закосить" под тулбар. так, как вы хотите - не получится без костылей.

Comment: @Style-7 ну, может, человек хочет пасхалку сделать ;)

Comment: @Эникейщик, так у MenuItem и нет setOnLongClickListener